# Selenium Firefox proxy setup with authentication

Tags: selenium, firefox, proxy

I am trying to send request with proxies, the problem is, if I use IP:Port proxies, my script work fine, but if I use IP:Port which ask for username and password too, that case my script unable to connect website.

How can I set up proxies properly with Firefox Selenium?

Here is the code:

```
import time

from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# profile_path = r'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\temp\FirefoxPortable\Data'
options=Options()
# options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', 'myhostgoes here')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port',12323)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_username",'myusername goes here')
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_password",'Password goes here')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', True)

service = Service(r'C://SeleniumDrivers/geckodriver.exe')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.whoer.net")
time.sleep(15)
driver.close()
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.whoer.net")
```

Comment: I found solution for chrome browser but firefox issue is still persist. please help to find solution for this problem.

Comment: Do you get any errors from the code, or is there anything interesting on the (Selenium) browser console?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949997/how-to-get-selenium-webdriver-to-use-socks-proxy) suggests the proxy format is different - might be a different driver though. Maybe worth a try?

Comment: i get Unable to connect error, i tried to other site but still nothing open , i wonder if its proxies issue, then at least it should open website directly, i mean without changing ip.

Comment: Thanks halfer , i will try the solution you mentioned in second comment and share my experience.

Comment: Halfer, i just rechecked again and found that the reference thread is using proxies without authentication, with my experience i confirm it works, i did it in past, here i am facing problem where pop up comes after setting up proxies and ask for username and password. So I am facing problem in setting up proxies in firefox which use authentication (username and password) before opening any website.